# Passing the variables from one of the function to another

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a button and a dropdown list with the lightning component like below where when I click on the button it shows a popup with the dropdown. I am trying to call Apex Class method (where I need to be using Case Id in SOQL query) on the selection of the dropdown is made

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global"  controller="manageCase"  >
  <aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>         
  <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Transfer Case" onclick="{! c.openModel }" />
  <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">

   <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
       <div class="slds-modal__container">
          <header class="slds-modal__header">
          <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"                                                  onclick="{! c.closeModel }" alternativeText="close"                                                   variant="bare-inverse" class="slds-modal__close"/>
           <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Transfer Case </h2>
           <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
           <lightning:select aura:id="select" name="select" label="Select" onchange="{! c.onChange }">
                            <option value="">choose one...</option>
                            <option value ="JaxServices">Jax Services</option> 
                            <option value="Pending-External">Pending-External</option>
                        </lightning:select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </aura:if>
 </aura:component>
```

The onclick functions for both the button and dropdown are like below

```
({
   openModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      var caseId = component.get('v.recordId');
      component.set("v.isOpen", true);
   },

  onChange: function (component, event, helper) {

       var dropdownSelection = component.find('select').get('v.value');
       var action = component.get("c.transferCase");

       action.setParams({caseId: component.get('v.recordId'), dept: dropdownSelection});
       action.setCallback(this, result => {
       .........
```

I am not sure how I can get the recordId (caseId) from the openModal function in to OnChange function. The `component.get('v.recordId')` is null in the OnChange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add force:hasRecordId to your component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" ...
```